# CommonJS in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, commonjs

Can I use `CommonJS` modules in a Chrome extensions?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since CommonJS implementations are server side, the only way to use that as a Chrome Extension is through NPAPI bindings. If your looking for alternate frameworks, look for ones that live in the client side.

Hope that helped!

Comment: CommonJS isn't just for server-side code. For example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/addon-development/commonjs.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use CommonJS's AMD module system as implemented by RequireJS quite nicely.

Comment: Links for your convenience: [AMD](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition), [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You may need a CommonJS client-side implementation, such as [SeaJS](http://seajs.org).